# How come I'm not getting the same output at the EAout, with the unity-gain buffer EAOUT output follows the +IN input

Tags: analog, isolated, error-amplifier

[image][image]The EAout pin does not output the same signal as +IN, the signal is coming from a voltage divider after full bridge rectification

Comment: Please show your full schematic - it looks like there may be something interesting off the top of the picture...

Comment: I have edited the post with a schematic picture, let me know what are your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exceeding the input range of the op amp.  Your input signal must be limited to a value between 0.35 and 1.5 volts for proper operation:

[image]

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your insight. I have changed the input common mode range to 1.2V and the signal is much better. Just one more question the output stays low during each second curve and I'm not too sure, from my understanding with the buffer I thought the output would have been exactly the same.

Comment: It's because of your grounding.  V1 is a sine wave referenced to ground, so it swings both positive and negative.  When it swings negative with respect to ground, a positive voltage cannot appear on V_Div.  Instead, the voltage on R3 goes negative.  Try letting V1 float and grounding R3 and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally the outcome I'm looking for. Now to build this circuit up!